# Efficiently evaluate an entire BSpline basis in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a sequence of knots of a cubic spline in the NumPy array `knots`, and I would like to efficiently evaluate an entire cubic BSpline basis which is represented by the array of knots at a certain point `x`. What I am currently doing is constructing the basis using the SciPy `scipy.interpolate.BSpline` class:

```py
from scipy.interpolate import BSpline

def bspline_basis(knots):
    return [
        BSpline.basis_element(knots[i:(i+5)], extrapolate=False)
        for i in range(len(knots) - 4)
    ]
```

and then using the returned basis for evaluation:

```py
def eval_basis(basis, x):
    return [elem(val).item() for elem in basis]
```

However, since the `eval_basis` function is repeatedly called millions of times, the above code is slow! The `BSpline` object is optimized for operating on arrays, and I am feeding it with individual scalars `x` and extracting the scalars from the resulting arrays.

Due to the fact that I operate in an existing codebase where I cannot change the call protocol to `eval_basis`, it has to be called on individual scalars `x`.

The code can clearly be accelerated if I could somehow efficiently evaluate an entire BSpline basis at a point `x` and obtain an NumPy array of the basis function values. Is there such a way using SciPy, or another Python library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.interpolate._bspl.evaluate_all_bspl` is undocumented but gets it done

Comment: Since it's undocumented, maybe add some context and code to your answer to show how to use it?

Comment: I don't know in which versions it exists, but in the official scipy repository  seems that it does not exist:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/_bsplines.py

Comment: Indeed, it's `_bspl.evaluate_all_bspl`. It might grow a public interface at some point, but today you can use the non-public, internal version (caveat emptor)